# Mismatch in p-value vs 95% CI in a lmer model?

Tags: r, lme4

I ran the following model

```
m1 <- lmer ( XX ~ XX_cov
 +  time + time:group + ZZ_cov + YY_cov 
             + age + (1 | ID), data = dat_long0 )
```

summary(m1)

```
> Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method
> [lmerModLmerTest ] Formula: XX ~ XX_cov + time + time:group + ZZ_cov +  YY_cov + age + (1 | ID)    Data: dat_long0
> 
> REML criterion at convergence: 717.7
> 
> Scaled residuals: 
>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
> -1.89415 -0.45047 -0.06034  0.48461  2.05636 
> 
> Random effects:  Groups       Name        Variance Std.Dev.  ID
> (Intercept) 2172     46.60     Residual                 1323     36.37
> Number of obs: 70, groups:  ID, 38
> 
> Fixed effects:
>                        Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|) 
>    (Intercept)         -24.9973   128.9808  32.4336  -0.194   0.8475  
> XX_cov                   1.0341     0.0237  31.9148  43.638   <2e-16 ***
> time4month               4.3200    13.0778  31.0297   0.330   0.7434  
> ZZ_cov                   1.0780     1.9248  31.3893   0.560   0.5794   
> YY_cov                  -0.3250     0.7727  31.4504  -0.421   0.6769   
> age                     -0.8934     1.4077  33.3841  -0.635   0.5300  
> time3month:groupINT     29.0811    20.2817  45.2350   1.434   0.1585    
> time4month:groupINT     39.8567    20.2420  45.0608   1.969   0.0551 .  
> --- Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> 
>
```

```
confint(m1)
Computing profile confidence intervals ...
                              2.5 %     97.5 %

> .sig01                   27.8284349  57.737186 
> .sigma                    28.0552001  46.208572 
> (Intercept)            -262.7058080 212.808179
>  XX_cov         0.9903383   1.077746
>  time4month       -20.4348285  31.026724 
> ZZ_cov                  -2.4706789   4.625220 
> yy_cov                  -1.7494582   1.100964 
> age                     -3.4923461   1.701046 
> time3month:groupINT   -8.3320707  66.682173 
> time4month:groupINT    2.2012439  77.166030
```

```
confint(m1, method="Wald")
                              2.5 %     97.5 %


> .sig01                 NA         NA 
> .sigma                 NA         NA 
> (Intercept) -277.7950825 227.800495
> XX_cov         0.9876227   1.080512 
> time4month   -21.3120670  29.952129 
> ZZ_cov        -2.6945146   4.850479 
> yy_cov        -1.8394953   1.189526 
> age           -3.6524536   1.865584 
> time3month:groupINT   -10.6704267  68.832523 
> time4month:groupINT     0.1831614  79.530222
```

How can this be? 95%CI does not cross the null.

Edit: just to add that N is small (40 participants and two time points at follow up)

Comment: Is there any chance we could have a reproducible example?

Comment: Please don't cross the streams (i.e. contact me on Twitter to respond to a comment on Stack Overflow) ...

Comment: voting to close & migrate to CrossValidated. It would be useful to see more complete info (e.g. full output of `summary()`, `confint()`, and `confint(method = "Wald")` (as text, not screenshot/image).

Comment: I have updated the first post with that data. I hope the format is ok for you. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hard to be sure without a reproducible example, but `summary()` and `confint()` use different methods as discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/117769/2126). The output from `summary()` is based on *Wald estimates*, which are faster but less accurate than *likelihood ratio tests*/*likelihood profile CIs*.

- `confint(., method = "Wald")` will give you Wald confidence intervals (which should match the results from `summary()`
- `drop1()` or `anova()` will give you likelihood ratio test p-values (which should match the results from `confint()`

It's difficult to get the likelihood ratio test p-value for a *single parameter* (e.g. `time4month:groupINT`) without doing extra work; likelihood ratio tests are usually done at the level of *terms* (e.g. `time:group`). On the other hand, it rarely makes sense to worry about the p-values of individual parameters that are part of a multi-parameter term ...

Furthermore, `confint(., method = "Wald")` does not correct the degrees of freedom - it uses a Gaussian rather than a t-distribution.

The CI range for the Gaussian is mean ± 1.96*SE, whereas for a t-distribution with 45 degrees of freedom it is mean ± `qt(0.975, 45)`*SE = mean ± 2.01*SE.  Comparing for your example:

```r
## lower CI for Gaussian
> 39.8567 - qnorm(0.975)*20.2420
[1] 0.183109
## lower CI for t distribution
> 39.8567 - qt(0.975, 45)*20.2420
[1] -0.9127808
```

... which explains your discrepancy, I think.

Unfortunately, likelihood profile confidence intervals (which are in general more accurate than Wald confidence intervals) are hard to apply finite-size corrections to ...

I would probably try parametric bootstrap intervals (`confint(., method = "boot")`), which will be time-consuming but in principle most accurate.

Comment: Sorry Ben.  confint(m1, method="Wald") still does not cross the null: 0.1831614  to 79.530222

Comment: In this case, you would still report the 95CI of confint and try to not worry much about it? Thanks